# Can I add a column to a temporary table that stores part of a date (year) from another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I want to select all columns from a table into a #temp1 table based on criteria.
In addition, I want to add an additional column that is the year portion only of a captured date field. I want the original whole date and add a separate column of just the year part of each date.

I tried to alter the #temp1 table and add a column called EnteredYear.
I then tried an update with a set EnteredYear = DATEPART(year, EnteredDate), but I am getting a syntax error.

Searching learn.microsoft.com and StackOverflow, but I haven't hit upon the right syntax yet.

Comment: When selecting, just add a derived column to the select list, to be part of the result used to create/populate the temp table.  No need to update.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can try to use the computed column which needs to `ALTER TABLE` because it is a schema change.

```
ALTER TABLE #Temp ADD EnteredYear AS DATEPART(year, EnteredDate)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f2a67fde9cc936b19eba823da747b2ae)

Comment: OMG! Thank you@D-Shih!
Bookmarking that link as well!

Comment: @shykitten No problem glad to help you can mark this answer If that help you

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables work almost like persisten tables. You manipulate them wit INSERT, UPDATE DELETE statements. So if you have already added your new column you could write:

```
UPDATE #temp1 set EnteredYear = DATEPART(year, EnteredDate)
```